# Finding common prime divisors

Tags: c

I've written a program to find common prime divisors, the greatest common divisor and the least common multiple. My method is finding the **gcd** first and then decompose the **gcd** into prime factors. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int x) {
    int y;
    for (y = 2; y < x; y++) {
        if (x % y != 0)
            continue;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    int n, m, i, gcd, lcm, k;
    // Input m and n
    printf("Enter m = ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter n = ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    // Common prime divisors
    lcm = m * n;
    while (m != n)
        if (m > n) m = m - n;
        else n = n - m;
    gcd = m;
    lcm = lcm / gcd;
    if (m <= 1)
        printf("No common prime divisors");
    else {
        printf("Common prime divisors: ");
        for (i = 2; i <= m - 1; i++) {
            k = prime(i);
            if (k = 1)
                if (m % i == 0)
                    printf("%d  ", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\nGreatest common divisor: %d\nLeast common multiple: %d", gcd, lcm);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the program is working but when I type m = 2 and n = 4 the common prime divisors, which is supposed to be '2', doesn't appear.
So what's wrong in my code?

Comment: This is really a good case a debugger can help to solve.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What is the gcd you get for 2 and 4? Did you mind higher powers of prime factors?

Comment: Why isn't GCD in a function?  Your prime function isn't efficient.  It also returns 1 when the number is not prime and 0 when it is, which is the reverse of the normal C convention (return 1 or true when it is prime; return 0 or false when not).  However, these are not directly your problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch it appears nothing

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. I think I need to rewrite my prime function.

Comment: "nothing" is not a value which can be contained in the variable `gcd` of type `int`; not after it has first been assigned.

Comment: @Yunnosch this was what I got: `Common prime divisors: `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m = 2`, then, the below loop can't execute because `2-1 = 1`, and `i` starts out at `2`.

```
for (i = 2; i <= m - 1; i++)
```

Additionally, `if (k=1)` is an assignment.  You want `if (k==1)`.

Comment: maybe I need to add one more line `if (m = 2) printf("Common prime divisors: 2");`

Comment: it doesn't work. when I enter `3` and `9` I got the same things

Comment: I think it works when I fix `i <= m - 1` to `i <= m`